# Send a String To a Action and Get Json Resualt

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm a beginner in jquery and ajax.
I have an action that retrives my data and I want to have access to this action by ajax.

My action:

```
public JsonResult FillSubject(string GroupServiceID)
{
    //string GSID = GroupServiceID.Substring(1, (GroupServiceID.Length)-2);
    var Subjects = db.Subjects.Where(c => c.GroupServicesID.ToString() == GroupServiceID);
    var SubjectList = Subjects.Select(sl => new SubjectList { ID = sl.ID, GroupServiceID = sl.GroupServicesID, strSubjectName = sl.strSubjectName });
    return Json(SubjectList);
}
```

and my jquery(ajax):

```
<script>
    function FillSubject() {
        var GroupServicesId = $('#GroupServices_ID').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "Advertisements/FillSubject",
            type: "GET",
            data: { 'GroupServiceID': GroupServicesId },
            success: function (Subjects) {
                $("#Subject_ID").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                $.each(Subjects, function (subject) {
                    $("#Subject_ID").append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(subject.ID).html(subject.strSubjectName));
                });
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert(this.url);
            },
        });
    }
</script>
```

My jquery code is run by changing in my dropdown.
This is my first dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GroupServices_ID, new SelectList(GroupServicesList, "ID", "strGroupServiceName"), new { @class = "selectpicker", @onchange = "FillSubject()" })
```

and result is added to the second dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Subject_ID, new SelectList(SubjectsList, "ID", "strSubjectName"), new { @class = "selectpicker" })`
```

Data is not received from my action and my script shows an error.

update 1 : 6/22/2016

my controller :

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MeydanMvc.Models;
using MeydanMvc.Models.Infrastructure;

namespace MeydanMvc.Controllers
{
    public class AdvertisementsController : Controller
    {
        private DataBaseContext db = new DataBaseContext();

        // GET: Advertisements
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var advertisements = db.Advertisements.Include(a => a.Acting).Include(a => a.Advertiser);
            return View(advertisements.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Advertisements/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(Guid? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Advertisement advertisement = db.Advertisements.Find(id);
            if (advertisement == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(advertisement);
        }

        // GET: Advertisements/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.Acting, "Advertisement_ID", "strFieldOfStudy");
            ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.Advertiser, "ID", "strName");
            ViewBag.GroupServices = db.GroupServices.ToList();
            ViewBag.Subjects = db.Subjects.ToList();
            return View();
        }
        public IList<Subject> GetSubject(Guid GroupSrvicesID)
        {
            return db.Subjects.Where(m => m.GroupServicesID == GroupSrvicesID).ToList();
        }

        public JsonResult GetJsonSubject(Guid GroupSrvicesID)
        {

            var subjectListt = this.GetSubject(GroupSrvicesID);
            var subjectList = subjectListt.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = m.strSubjectName,
                Value = m.ID.ToString()
            });

            return Json(subjectList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult FillSubject(string GroupServiceID)
        {
            //string GSID = GroupServiceID.Substring(1, (GroupServiceID.Length)-2);
            var Subjects = db.Subjects.Where(c => c.GroupServicesID.ToString() == GroupServiceID);
            var SubjectList = Subjects.Select(sl => new SubjectList { ID = sl.ID, GroupServiceID = sl.GroupServicesID, strSubjectName = sl.strSubjectName });
            return Json(SubjectList,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        public ActionResult Test(int id)
        {
            string message = "سلام";
            if(id==0)
            {
                return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                message = "خداحافظ";
                return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        // POST: Advertisements/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,strAdvertisementTitle,dtStartDate,dtEndDate,tsStartTime,tsEndTime,Discription,iWage,iPhoneNumber1,iPhoneNumber2,strEmail,bOccasion,IsActive,InsertTime,UpdateTime,IsDeleted,DeletedTime")] Advertisement advertisement)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                advertisement.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
                db.Advertisements.Add(advertisement);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.Acting, "Advertisement_ID", "strFieldOfStudy", advertisement.ID);
            ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.Advertiser, "ID", "strName", advertisement.ID);
            return View(advertisement);
        }

        // GET: Advertisements/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(Guid? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Advertisement advertisement = db.Advertisements.Find(id);
            if (advertisement == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.Acting, "Advertisement_ID", "strFieldOfStudy", advertisement.ID);
            ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.Advertiser, "ID", "strName", advertisement.ID);
            return View(advertisement);
        }

        // POST: Advertisements/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,strAdvertisementTitle,dtStartDate,dtEndDate,tsStartTime,tsEndTime,Discription,iWage,iPhoneNumber1,iPhoneNumber2,strEmail,bOccasion,IsActive,InsertTime,UpdateTime,IsDeleted,DeletedTime")] Advertisement advertisement)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(advertisement).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.Acting, "Advertisement_ID", "strFieldOfStudy", advertisement.ID);
            ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.Advertiser, "ID", "strName", advertisement.ID);
            return View(advertisement);
        }

        // GET: Advertisements/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(Guid? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Advertisement advertisement = db.Advertisements.Find(id);
            if (advertisement == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(advertisement);
        }

        // POST: Advertisements/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(Guid id)
        {
            Advertisement advertisement = db.Advertisements.Find(id);
            db.Advertisements.Remove(advertisement);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

and my view

```
@model MeydanMvc.Models.Advertisement

@{
    Layout = null;
    var GroupServicesList = ViewBag.GroupServices as IEnumerable<MeydanMvc.Models.GroupServices>;
    var SubjectsList = ViewBag.Subjects as IEnumerable<MeydanMvc.Models.Subject>;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Create</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    function FillSubject() {

        var GroupServicesId = $('#GroupServices_ID').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Advertisements/FillSubject",
            type: "GET",
            data: { 'GroupServiceID': GroupServicesId },
            dataType:"json",
            success: function (Subjects) {
                $("#Subject_ID").html("");
                $.each(Subjects, function (i, subject) {
                    $("#Subject_ID").append($('<option></option>').val(subject.ID).html(subject.strSubjectName));
                });
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert(this.url);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Advertisement</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.strAdvertisementTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strAdvertisementTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strAdvertisementTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GroupServices_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GroupServices_ID, new SelectList(GroupServicesList, "ID", "strGroupServiceName"), new { @class = "selectpicker", @onchange = "FillSubject()" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GroupServices_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subject_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Subject_ID, new SelectList(SubjectsList, "ID", "strSubjectName"), new { @class = "selectpicker" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dtStartDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dtStartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dtStartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dtEndDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dtEndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dtEndDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tsStartTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tsStartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tsStartTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tsEndTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tsEndTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tsEndTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Discription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Discription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Discription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.iWage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.iWage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.iWage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.iPhoneNumber1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.iPhoneNumber1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.iPhoneNumber1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.iPhoneNumber2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.iPhoneNumber2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.iPhoneNumber2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.strEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.strEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.strEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.bOccasion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.bOccasion)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.bOccasion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsActive)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InsertTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InsertTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InsertTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UpdateTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UpdateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UpdateTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsDeleted, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsDeleted)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsDeleted, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeletedTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeletedTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeletedTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>


    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**I run project but my script run error method**

update 2 6/22/2016

I Change my controller and give json result in ajax but don't update my second dropdown
My result
    `[Object { ID="ffb1d85a-a822-41e1-8859-24db2b5bc72e",  GroupServiceID="0cc2cdf6-b9d3-4274-9cc1-31daf5814458",  strSubjectName="برنامه نویسی"}, Object { ID="1f65f038-0111-479a-bdf3-d43eb772af9d",  GroupServiceID="0cc2cdf6-b9d3-4274-9cc1-31daf5814458",  strSubjectName="آموزش زبان خارجه"}]`

Comment: What is the error are you getting? Can you try by using JSON.stringify({ 'GroupServiceID': GroupServicesId }) for data?

Comment: my error is [object object]

Comment: i use JSON.stringify({ 'GroupServiceID': GroupServicesId })  but nothing return and get error

Comment: _my script show error_ - What error? -(it needs to be `return Json(SubjectList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`);`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, change your `FillSubject` action in the controller like this:

```
return Json(SubjectList,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Secondly, copy and paste the javascript below over what you have.You had some missing closing braces and brackets and your `$.each` loop was wrong:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function FillSubject() {

        var GroupServicesId = $('#GroupServices_ID').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Advertisements/FillSubject",
            type: "GET",
            data: { 'GroupServiceID': GroupServicesId },
            success: function (Subjects) {
                $("#Subject_ID").html("");
                $.each(Subjects, function (i, subject) {
                    $("#Subject_ID").append($('<option></option>').val(subject.ID).html(subject.strSubjectName));
                });
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert(this.url);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: My script run but not run success ajax method and go to error method

Comment: Please replace all your code with what I posted.It's working on my side.I tested it.And remember to change the FillSubject action method in the controller to return like this - return Json(SubjectList,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: You still haven't changed Json(SubjectList,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: I Changed , this my code  '[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult FillSubject(string GroupServiceID)
        {
            //string GSID = GroupServiceID.Substring(1, (GroupServiceID.Length)-2);
            var Subjects = db.Subjects.Where(c => c.GroupServicesID.ToString() == GroupServiceID);
            var SubjectList = Subjects.Select(sl => new SubjectList { ID = sl.ID, GroupServiceID = sl.GroupServicesID, strSubjectName = sl.strSubjectName });
            return Json(SubjectList,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }'

Comment: You might have a routing issue,try comment out EVERY SINGLE action method in your controller except for FillSubject and Index and try again.If that works then you know you have a routing problem otherwsise I have no idea what the problem is.Like I said in my AdvertisementsController I only have Index and FillSubject and it works perfectly fine

Comment: I add debugger in error function and get e.responseText. I see undefined in alert

Comment: So now it magically started working?Change your drop down to this and test - <select id="Subject_ID"></select> lace a debugger; inside the $.each function and use the Google Chrome console to test it

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps:

change the controller action like the below one:

```
  public ActionResult SomeActionMethod() {
      //string GSID = GroupServiceID.Substring(1, (GroupServiceID.Length)-2);
        var Subjects = db.Subjects.Where(c => c.GroupServicesID.ToString() == GroupServiceID);
        var SubjectList = Subjects.Select(sl => new SubjectList { ID = sl.ID, GroupServiceID = sl.GroupServicesID, strSubjectName = sl.strSubjectName });
        return Json(SubjectList);
   }
```

and then make the following ajax call:

```
     $.getJSON("Advertisements/FillSubject", 
               { 'GroupServiceID':GroupServicesId },
             function(data) {
                alert(data);

          }
      );
```

Comment: This solution not currect for my project tnx for replay

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
<script>
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Advertisements/FillSubject",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { 'GroupServiceID': GroupServicesId },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var ddlCustomers = $("[id*=Subject_ID]");
        ddlCustomers.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">--Please select--</option>');
        $.each(data, function (i, v) {
            ddlCustomers.append($("<option</option>", { value: v.ID, text: v.strSubjectName}));
        });
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + "_" + errorThrown);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified some changes in your ajax code.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "Advertisements/FillSubject",
        type: "GET",
        data: {GroupServiceID: GroupServicesId },
        success: function (Subjects) {

        $.each(Subjects, function (index, itemData) {
         console.log(itemData.ID);
     //write append dropdown code here
        });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a new controller and add action in this controller.I can get result in Ajax method but I can't show my result in drop down because use I use Bootstrap-select for style and this is conflict by my Ajax function. I clear this component and run correctly project